# What does the different coloured smoke in Once Upon a Time mean?

Tags: once-upon-a-time

In Once Upon a Time, when you use magic we usually see that magic looks like colored smoke/mist like in this picture.

[image]

Is there a symbolic meaning behind the different colors when using magic or is it just for show?

E.g. Rumplestilskins magic looks red, Zelenas is Green, Emmas is blue or maybe purple I think. Anyone know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, the meaning behind the colored smoke has never been explained. Each magic user seems to have their own personal color that tinges the magic they do, but if there is any deeper meaning to those colors it has not been specifically addressed.

It *has* been addressed that the colors are intentionally distinct. Regina recognizes the "green smoke" as being a signature of the Wicked Witch from Oz.

The colors do seem to be chosen intentionally to represent the person that uses them. Zelena's entire motivation now is jealousy (of Regina) so green fits her well, and Rumple is a very angry person, so he gets red. But I don't think it's as simple as the user's emotions choosing their color: remember that Zelena's magic was always green, long before her jealousy emerged and caused her skin to change. And Regina's purple smoke is the color of royalty, fitting her status as Evil Queen, but doesn't really match any of the emotions she tends to exhibit.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Emma's Magic is blue because it is light magic, rumple's is red because he has killed so many, Regina's is purple because she believes she is the most beautiful and fairest of them all, and Zelena's is green beacause of her envy of Regina, but before she became wicked, she was mad that her father didn't appreciate her and had envy over everyone else who was treated better than her. Last but not least, the good witch of the south (I think) has white magic that I think represents honesty, goodness, and wisdom

Answer (score 0):

Ice blue would be ice/snow power --
Green would be wicked magic--
Purple would be evil--
Red would be for blood and anger--
Black would be simply dark magic --
White would be simply light magic--
Gray (Emma as the dark one) would mean a mix of dark and light magic--
Royal blue (like for Merlin and the fairies would be fairy/sorcerer magic (like just where is comes from) --
orange I have no clue--
And there would be different shades of colors for mixes and just to recognize which character is using the magic --

Comment: Do you have a source for this information?